# Binary Search for a range

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

I was making binary search program to find the number of elements between the Left and Right values in a range .

I code it :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
vector<int> arr(20);
int search(int value,int low,int high) 
{
  if (high <= low)
      return low;
  int mid = (low + high) / 2;

  if (arr[mid] > value)
      return search(value,low,mid-1);
  else
      return search(value,mid+1,high);
}


int main(){
int n;
cin>>n;
//ENTER SORTED ARRAY
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>arr[i];
}


int left;
cin>>left;
//RIGHT IS GREATER OR EQUAL TO LEFT
int right;
cin>>right;
cout<<search(right,0,n-1)-search(left,0,n-1)+1<<"\n";

}
```

It's giving right answer for some ranges.
But for some its giving wrong like If N=6 and array be [1 3 5 8 10 13] and say the range be [5,9] then it's giving 1 as the answer but it should be 2 as 5 and 8 both are in the range.

Comment: This might or might not be related to your problem, but I'm curious what answer you would want this algorithm to give for your example set with `N==0`?  It appears that your algorithm can't give an answer that distinguishes between 1 element in the range and no element in the range.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I am assuming that both left and right are with i range of array

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2e49c838d017ace

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
int search(int value,int low,int high) 
{
if (high <= low)
  return low;
int mid = (low + high) / 2;
if(arr[mid]==value){      // add this line it would be work for you
    return mid;
}
if (arr[mid] > value)
  return search(value,low,mid-1);
else
  return search(value,mid+1,high);
}
```

and make correction in main()

```
cout<<search(right,0,n-1)-search(left,0,n-1)<<"\n";
```

Comment: Its still giving 1 for above example

Comment: because 9 is not present in you list so its take 10th postion value

Comment: but in my code it perfectly work if either number is present  or not

Comment: See 5 is at 2nd position assuming 0 based indexing and 9 would come at 4th position.So to numbers are their 5,8 between this range

Comment: i take your array if i search 9 then it give 1 difference if i am searching 11 which is also not present in list it give perfect answer because it depend on the position of greater or lesser number

Answer (score 1):

```
int search(int value,int low,int high) 
{
    if (high <= low + 1)
       return low;
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;

    if (arr[mid] > value)
       return search(value,low,mid);
    else
       return search(value,mid,high);
}
```

And in your main function

```
cout<<search(right+1,0,n-1)-search(left,0,n-1)<<"\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that when `arr[mid] == value`, you just ignore it and recurse to the right.

You'll need to either include `mid` in your right range, or return `mid` if `arr[mid] == value`.

I also see duplicate values (if these are possible) being a problem - when recursing to find the left-most position, you need to find the first duplicate value, when recursing to find the right-most position, you need to find the last duplicate value, so a single function without a flag to indicate which one we're doing isn't going to work. To illustrate the problem:

If the range is `[5,5]` and the input is `[1,2,5,5,5,6,8]`, the same recursive call finding the position of `5` will always return the position of the same `5`, where-as you need to return index `2` for the left range and index `4` for the right, as to get `3` as your output.

Comment: Their are no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

There is no check that `arr[mid]` can be == value. In your example, first iteration for  left == 5 gives mid == ( 0 + (6-1) )/2 =  5/2 = 2 and arr[2] is exactly 5. We should stop, but your code goes to the branch `search(5, 3, 5);`

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your program seems wrong, if you want to find the number of elements in the `arr` that are in the range of [left,right], try this:

```
 int i;
 int count = 0;
 for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     if (arr[i] >= left && arr[i] <= right)
         count++;
 }
```

If you insist on using binary search try this :

```
static int search(int value,int low,int high) 
{
    if (high <= low)
        return low;
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    if (arr[mid] == value)
        return mid;
    int idx;
    if (arr[mid] > value) 
        idx = search(value,low,mid-1);
    else 
        idx = search(value,mid+1,high); 
    if (value == arr[idx]) {
        return idx;
    }
    else {
        if(value > arr[idx])
            return mid +1;
        else
            return mid;
    }
}
```

Comment: You misinterpreted the question.

Comment: @user3405426: What I get is that you have sth like {1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 13} and want to find how many of these are in a range like [5,9],is it wrong?

Comment: Why do you search for 5 and 9 in the arr?

Comment: Yeah i want to do it by binary search by finding first find position of 5 then position of 9 in the array and then find numbers in this range which are in the array.

Comment: Simply use pencil under the water instead of a magical pen! Ok so I didn't misunderstood you completely but if you insist to use the binary search you should change the logic again, I'll complete my answer.